# Radio button malfunctioning when used inside label tag

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

i am working on html and CSS. i have to add 5 radio buttons to my page and i have added within `<label>` tag. but when i  look for the page. it shows all the radio buttons selected and also i am unable to unselect it. the thing is i need only one radio button selected at a time. here is my code.

```
<label class="radio"><input type="radio"> Pepse</label> 
<label class="radio"><input type="radio"> Coke</label> 
<label class="radio"><input type="radio">Mirinda</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="radio">Maaza </label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

radio buttons require a common name. If you don't give them a `name` attribute, each radio button essentially becomes a one-way checkbox. You can select them, but you can't UNselect them.

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="2" />

<input type="radio" value="3" />
```

In this case, the two `foo` radio buttons will be linked internally because they are both named the same, but the one with value `3` will be completely independent and act as your are.

Comment: Fantastic marc B. has anybody said you Genius. It worked fine. Thank you very much for this sparking fact.

Answer (score 0):

Add a group name.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhLaa/)

```
<label class="radio"><input name="drinks" type="radio">Pepse</label>
<label class="radio"><input name="drinks" type="radio">Coke</label>
<label class="radio"><input name="drinks" type="radio">Mirinda</label>
<label class="radio"><input name="drinks" type="radio">Maaza </label>
<label class="radio"><input name="drinks" type="radio">Milk Frothers</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.agroup of radios need a **name** so that the browser know which one is selected

2.if u want to put the label outside of the input u can use the **for** attribute
to tell the browser that this label is for that radio with the same **id**

```
<label for="a">a</label>
<input type="radio" name="aname" id="a" value="a"><br>
<label for="b">b</label>
<input type="radio" name="aname" id="b" value="b"><br>
<label for="c">c</label>
<input type="radio" name="aname" id="c" value="c"><br>
<label for="d">d</label>
<input type="radio" name="aname" id="d" value="d"><br>
```

but i also prefer radios inside labels so

```
<label><input type="radio" name="aname" value="a">a</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="aname" value="b">b</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="aname" value="c">c</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="aname" value="d">d</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="aname" value="e">e</label><br>
```

3.in a common way they also need a value, except ur using js

```
<label><input type="radio" name="aname">a</label><br>
<script>
document.write(document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue)
</script>
```

writes a after `<br>`